# Binance Futures API: How to get specific asset balance?

Tags: python-3.x, binance

i'm trying to create a bot on binance and i'd like to know my USDT balance on futures, and use that specific information.
Here's the code i used so far (from Binance Futures API examples):

```
from binance_f import RequestClient
from binance_f.constant.test import *
from binance_f.base.printobject import *
from binance_f.model.constant import *

request_client = RequestClient(api_key=g_api_key, secret_key=g_secret_key, url='https://fapi.binance.com/')
result = request_client.get_balance()
```

Response:

```
[{"accountAlias":"mYsRTiAuuXfWXq","asset":"BNB","balance":"0.00000000","withdrawAvailable":"0.00000000","updateTime":0},{"accountAlias":"mYsRTiAuuXfWXq","asset":"USDT","balance":"7.00000000","withdrawAvailable":"7.00000000","updateTime":1618005754464},{"accountAlias":"mYsRTiAuuXfWXq","asset":"BUSD","balance":"0.00000000","withdrawAvailable":"0.00000000","updateTime":0}]
```

So far so good i get my USDT balance, but i'd like to use it as a variable( a = usdt balance), i know it's trivial but can someone explain please ?

Balance model:

```
class Balance:

    def __init__(self):
        self.asset = ""
        self.accountAlias = ""
        self.balance = 0.0
        self.withdrawAvailable = 0.0

    @staticmethod
    def json_parse(json_data):
        result = Balance()
        result.asset = json_data.get_string("asset")
        result.accountAlias = json_data.get_string("accountAlias")
        result.balance = json_data.get_float("balance")
        result.withdrawAvailable = json_data.get_float("withdrawAvailable")

        return result
```

Comment: Maybe, I am a little dense, but I don't understand your question.  As you indicate the response from ```result = request_client.get_balance()``` is a list of dictionaries containing the data of interest.  Do you want to know how to build class instances of your class Balance' for each account listed in response, or something else?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear to you, i asked how to get specific datas from that dictionary and use it as a variable, i just didn't know how to use that dictionnary, but the solution was just:

 result[position of the asset in the dictionary].balance

,thx tho

Answer (score 0):

```
balance = result[1]['balance']
```

Should do the trick.

The response is a python list of dictionaries.